# Differentiability at a "corner" in a physical sense

Tags: derivatives, physics, absolute-value

In calculus, everyone learns that functions are not differentiable at  corners, with the absolute value function often given as a prime example.

Now consider a cow whose position vs. time function is $x(t)=|t-4|$. Obviously, the derivative of this function or the cow's velocity vs. time function is $x'(t)=\frac{t-4}{|t-4|}$. We also know that the cow's position function is not differentiable at $t=4$. From my understanding, this is because the line tangent to $x(t)$ at $t=4$ can have any slope value in between $-1$ and $1$ and is thus not unique. Mathematically, it does not seem like we can know the cow's velocity at this point.

Now thinking physically, whether it is $0$ or some other constant in between $-1$ and $1$, the cow must have a velocity at $t=4$.

My question is, how could we determine it mathematically if we cannot differentiate the cow's position function at $t=4$? Is there even enough information to mathematically determine the cow's velocity at this time? I can't really figure out what other information we need.

I know in physics, when using indefinite integrals, the constant of integration, $C$, often pops up as some initial value. I cannot figure out if this sort of thinking is applicable to my question.

Comment: As far as I know, the classical kynematic interpretation of this "bouncing" phenomenon would be that supposedly the cow never stops out of the blue, but rather that it should brake very rapidly and then accelerate equally rapidly in the opposite direction.

Comment: Perhaps the equation is not a physically realistic model of the cow's motion?

Comment: @saulspatz Hmm... that's an interesting point. I just used a cow for the amusement value but I see what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the cow you are talking about changes its direction abruptly. When it approaches $0$ (distance) before time $t = 4$, it is moving in the negative direction with a constant (unit) speed, and hence the calculated velocity is $-1$. After the moment $t = 4$, i.e., for $t > 4$, the cow starts moving in the positive direction, again with a constant (unit) speed. Therefore you get the velocity $1$.

However, at the exact time $t = 4$, the cow "reverses" its direction so that velocity cannot be determined. I hope you get the essence of what problem occurs at "corners".